# How to keep VSCode remote tunnel connection going when the remote device is off

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, remote-tunnel

I have used the VSCodes remote tunnel feature on my ipad via vscode.dev to connect to my laptop. The issue is that I don't want to keep my laptop on all the time while I am connecting to it with my ipad.

I asked phind.com to help me but the AI just suggested that I stop my device from sleeping entirely or run the remote tunnel as a service using this command "code tunnel install" which I don't exactly understand but it didn't work anyways.